# Nuget Package Conflict in Dependencies

Tags: nuget

I found that my console app (.NET Core 2.2) was blowing up because there seemed to be some kind of conflict between dependencies for JSON.NET (Newtonsoft).

This was the exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Upon further investigation, I discovered the cause of the exception, which I will lay out below.

I have a reference to a local Project which depends on JSON.NET. Let's call it `SomeDomain`. That relies on v12.0.2 of JSON.NET.

I also have installed (by way of Nuget), the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` (v2.2.0) which also relies on JSON.NET. If you go to the Nuget.org page for that version of that package, you'll see the version dependancy is >= 11.0.2

I'm thinking "sweet".

Not so.

When I publish, it is resolving v11.0.2 of JSON.NET. And this leads to an exception, because `SomeDomain` depends on v12.0.2 .

In an attempt to resolve this, I added v12.0.2 of JSON.NET directly to the app. I figured this would force it to use that version. Not so. It still resolves v11.0.2 of JSON.NET upon Publish.

Does anyone know how I can force it to resolve v12.0.2 of JSON.NET when I publish my app?

Comment: This seems quite odd to me as NuGet should have resolved to version the higher version in both your cases. Which version of NuGet are you using? Can you try with latest version?

Comment: @AnandGaurav I am using 5.4.0 of Nuget Package Manager.

Comment: May be a bug with publish. File an issue with NuGet and provide a repro. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues

Comment: @AnandGaurav Just a quick update. This resolved itself somehow. If I were to try and identify anything which may have triggered the update, I changed the version of the exes which I was building in my projects (we don't have an automated build). For some reason, after I did that, the correct Nuget packages were being used.